# Rspec giving me invalid option --format error?

Tags: rspec

If I type the following in terminal

```
rspec spec --format documentation
```

Then I get this error

```
invalid option: --format
```

Whereas on this site https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/format-option, it says it works.

I've version 3.3.2 of Rspec.

Answer (score 2):

It really should work like that. I just tried in my application to make sure, and it works fine: `rspec spec --format documentation`

Do you have multiple `rspec` versions installed? check that.

And, try this:

```
bundle exec rspec spec --format documentation
```

see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, i still receive the same error. It's not just my computer either, i cloned that repo and on other computers i get the same error.